# C++ Run time Linker error (liblog4cpp.so.5) Eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, log4cpp

When I try to build and run the application I wrote from the Eclipse IDE, I am getting an error:

> "error while loading shared libraries: liblog4cpp.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

No compilation errors. But if I run the generated output file from the terminal, the application runs normally. When I use `ldd` for the application, all the libraries are lined.

From Eclipse, all the library paths are defined too.

project compiled build on Redhat7 OS and I use the log4cpp from  below location https://sourceforge.net/projects/log4cpp/

What should be the issue

Comment: Looks that or a symbolic link is missing or the file is not on the path, did you verify that?

Comment: Reinstall the package : Debian style → `$ sudo apt install --reinstall liblog4cpp5v5` .... Fedora style → `# dnf reinstall log4cpp`

Comment: It seems that you manage to build the executable but failing to run it from within Eclipse. This must indicate a setup error in the IDE configuration (maybe `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set correctly). When succeeding running it from the command line, did you set any environment variables in particular? Do you have the *liblog4cpp.so.5* locally inside the directory?

Comment: @camp0 all the library files are at the path /usr/lib

Comment: @Raz Haleva LD_LIBRARY_PATH are configured and when I run with terminal I do not set any environment variables

Comment: @KnudLarsen  when i install log4cpp and run get error"symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _ZN7log4cpp8Appender29AppenderMapStorageInitializerC1Ev
"

Comment: The error `symbol lookup error` indicates that the application was compiled on a different OS, or/and with different libraries. Please edit your question to include relevant OS specification, and the libraries you compiled against.

Comment: I have finally fixed the issue by manually copying the library files to /usr/local/lib64

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling `iblog4cpp5v5` worked for me. You can do with:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall liblog4cpp5v5
```